# Perl: for loop / string manipulation

Tags: string, perl, for-loop, string-matching

I am new to perl and I would like to replicate my code written in awk into perl.
I want to replicate a particular line number of times depending on string matched at position.

Sample input file:

```
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
text Ix A(Ay) test text
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
```

While reading this input file I would check for "Ix" string in the second position and repeat it number of times. (3 times as shown in the Sample output)

Sample Output file

```
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
text I1 A(A3) test text
text I2 A(A2) test text
text I3 A(A1) test text
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
```

Any help would be appriciated.

regards

---

My failing code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $loop=0;
my $max=3;
my $in_file="$ARGV[0]";

open (PH, "$in_file") or die "check file";
while (<PH>) {
chomp;
if ($_ =~ /Ix/) {
    $loop=0;
    while ($loop < $max) {
        my $local = $max-$loop;
        $_ =~ s/Ix/I$loop/;
        $_ =~ s/Ay/A$local/;
        print "$_\n";
        $loop++;
        }
    } else {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
close(PH);
```

I am looking for somthing like "$2 ~ /Ix/" in awk that I could place in my if-condition. I am not sure if perl allows you to do that. Apart from the above, I am not able to use current value of $loop in the while itself.

Comment: There are lots of ways to write this code.  Please give us a real use case.

Comment: is the literal input exactly as shown?  "Ix", "Ay"?  is any y and x replaced or only the x after the I in the second field and the y (or multiple y's?) in the third field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your biggest problem is that you edit `$_`, so the second pass through the loop, there is no longer a "Ix" nor "Ay" in the string.

```
$loop=0;
while ($loop < $max) {
    my $local = $max-$loop;
    my $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/Ix/I$loop/;
    $line =~ s/Ay/A$local/;
    print "$line\n";
    $loop++;
}
```

You might also consider using a `for` loop:

```
   for my $loop (0 .. ($max - 1)) {
        my $local = ($max - $loop);
        my $line = $_;
        $line =~ s/Ix/I$loop/;
        $line =~ s/Ay/A$local/;
        print "$line\n";
    }
```

If these are space-delimited "columns" and you'd like to only edit the values in "columns" 2 and 3 (your mention of `$2` in `awk` seems to suggest that?) you can split the input as well: the `split` command intentionally emulates `awk`

From `perldoc -f split`:

```
        As another special case, "split" emulates the default behavior of
        the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a
        literal string composed of a single space character (such as ' '
        or "\x20", but not e.g. "/ /"). In this case, any leading
        whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the
        PATTERN is instead treated as if it were "/\s+/"; in particular,
        this means that any contiguous whitespace (not just a single space
        character) is used as a separator. However, this special treatment
        can be avoided by specifying the pattern "/ /" instead of the
        string " ", thereby allowing only a single space character to be a
        separator.

        If omitted, PATTERN defaults to a single space, " ", triggering
        the previously described awk emulation.
```

which brings us to:

```
local $" = ' ';                                                                                  #" (syntax highlighting bug on SO)

my @input = split;
if ($input[1] =~ /Ix/) {
    for my $loop (0 .. ($max - 1)) {
        my $local = ($max - $loop);
        my @line = @input;
        $line[1] =~ s/Ix/I$loop/;
        $line[2] =~ s/Ay/A$local/;
        print "@line\n";
    }
} else {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

The special variable `$"` specifically means that `"@line"` will be printed with a `' '` between each element of the array, so you get your "columns" back in the output.

One last hint: your `die` can print a meaningful error message just by including `$!`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $loop=0;
my $max=3;
my $in_file="$ARGV[0]";

local $" = ' ';                                                                                  #" (syntax highlighting bug on SO)

open (PH, "$in_file") or die "check file: $!";
while (<PH>) {
    chomp;
    my @input = split;
    if ($input[1] =~ /Ix/) {
        for my $loop (0 .. ($max - 1)) {
            my $local = ($max - $loop);
            my @line = @input;
            $line[1] =~ s/Ix/I$loop/;
            $line[2] =~ s/Ay/A$local/;
            print "@line\n";
        }
    } else {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
close(PH);
```

**Edit:**

As @Kenosis pointed out in comments, the sample output you provided has the `I` counter running 1…3 rather than 0…2. In your loop, you were initializing the counter to 0 and incrementing it only after printing, so I had (mis-)interpreted that as your intention.

Fortunately, changing this is easy:

```
   for my $loop (1 .. $max) {
      my $local = (1+ $max - $loop);
      …
```

As also pointed out, using lexical (`my`) variables for file handles is generally safer/better for various technical reasons, as well;

```
  open my $ph, '<', $infile or die "Can't read $infile: $!";

  …

  while (<$ph>) {
  …
```

… although the older style filehandles that you used (bareword identifiers) still does work.
This also shows the "3-argument `open`", which prevents a number of possible security holes (or bizarre, head-scratchingly crazy behaviours) in the "2-arg" form, with the `<` prepended to the filename.

And, as @Kenosis notes, `$"` does happen to default to `' '`, but I tend to redefine it "just in case" (I personally have a *lot* of Perl code that redefines it as things like `','` or `"\t"` for various reasons, and you can `local`ly reset it to be sure of what your output will look like.)

Comment: As it is, this produces `text I0 .. text I2`. The default setting of Perl's `$"` is `' '`. Better to use lexical vars, not barewords, for file handles.

Comment: Ah; I was mimicking the behaviour I thought he wanted from the code, I see now that the example output did actually have 1…3 rather than 0…2 there. Agreed on lexicals, but trying to resemble the original code so he can follow; `$"` just safety/paranoia. I'll edit the increment, though, to match.

Comment: All good points!  Knew the `I0 ..` was minor.  Nice help for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    if (/^\S+?\s+Ix\s+/) {
        my ( %h, $c ) = ( I => 1, A => -3 );
        $_ = join '',
          map { s/\b(I)x|(A)y\b/$c = $1 ? $1 : $2; $c . abs $h{$c}++/ge; $_ }
          my @lines = ($_) x 3;
    }

    print;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFIle]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
text I1 A(A3) test text
text I2 A(A2) test text
text I3 A(A1) test text
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
Dummy lines Ix Dummy lines
```

Hope this helps!